# How to prevent constructor parametres changing

Tags: javascript, class

I have a `class File`, and constructor that accept `fullname` parameter. How can i prevent changing of this? I tried it with setter and getter, but it doesnt work

```js
class File {
  constructor(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
  }
  get fullname() {
    return this.fullname;
  }
  set fullname(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      newValue = this.fullName;
    }
  }

}

let example = new File("example.txt");
example.fullName = "modified.txt";
console.log(example.fullName); // should be example.txt
```

Comment: Typo : `return this.fullName`

Comment: not related to the issue but inside the setter: `newValue = this.fullName;` --> `this.fullName = newValue;` and you need to fix the name of the setter: `fullname` --> `fullName`. Also rename the getter as well.

Comment: @TusharShahi, @Yousaf: That wouldn't really help because the getter/setter `fullname` is not triggered when accessing `fullName`.

Comment: @FelixKling right; I have suggested to the OP to fix the name of the setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a readonly property with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
class File {
  constructor(fullName) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
      enumerable: true,
      writable: false, // not necessary (because default) but more explicit,
      value: fullName,
    });
  }
}


let example = new File("example.txt");
example.fullName = "modified.txt";
console.log(example.fullName);
```

Note that assigning to the property would throw an error in *strict mode*.

---

If you want to be in strict mode but also want to silently ignore the assignment, you could take the `getter/setter` approach ~but you will still have to store the real value somewhere on the object, which means it could still be accessed and be modified if one knows which property to access.~ but it's a bit more evolved. You'd basically create a getter and setter for every instance, thus avoiding to have to store the original value on the object itself:

```js
"use strict";

class File {
  constructor(fullName) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
      enumerable: true,
      set: value => {}, // ignore
      get: () => fullName,
    });
  }
}


let example = new File("example.txt");
example.fullName = "modified.txt";
console.log(example.fullName);
```

[Private properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields), which are a relatively new feature of JavaScript, might make this a bit "nicer" (subjective):

```js
class File {
  #fullName;
  
  constructor(fullName) {
    this.#fullName = fullName;
  }
  get fullName() {
    return this.#fullName;
  }
  set fullName(newValue) {
    // ignore new value
  }

}

let example = new File("example.txt");
example.fullName = "modified.txt";
console.log(example.fullName);
```

Comment: Using private properties helped me, but i wonder why i have an error `Cannot assign to read only property 'fullName' of object '#<File>` in first method? Thanks for help

Comment: Ah, when you are in strict mode then trying to assign to a readonly property throws an error instead of silently ignoring it.

Answer (score 2):

Using ES2020+ syntax:

```js
class File {
  #fullName = null;
  
  constructor(fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
  }
  
  get fullName() {
    return this.#fullName;
  }
  
  set fullName(newValue) {
    this.#fullName ??= newValue;
  }
}

let example = new File("example.txt");
example.fullName = "modified.txt";
console.log(example.fullName); // should be example.txt
```

There are several places that you misspelled `fullName` to `fullname`, mind the cases matter in JavaScript.

Comment: FWIW, private properties are not part of ES6. I think they have been part of this year's release?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, thanks for pointing out. The `class` keyword is a part of ES6 syntax, but private fields and logical nullish assignment `??=` are much later ones.